# /pusher/auth endpoint returning 404 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I have built a Laravel app where I am trying to implement Web Sockets via Pusher.com (for the first time).

While I have got public channel subscriptions working fine, I am struggling getting private channels working correctly.

According to the laravel documentation you need to uncomment `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` in `app.php` config file which I have.

My channels.php has the following rule(s)

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('private-queue.business.{business}', function ($user, Business $business) {
    // @todo: add real authentication
    return true;
});
```

Is there anything else I need to add to get `/pusher/auth` endpoint working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Laravel 7.x, the Broadcasting endpoint is `broadcasting/auth` and not `pusher/auth`.

I needed to update my JS like so to be able to define a custom auth endpoint:

```
const pusher = new Pusher('{{ env('PUSHER_APP_KEY') }}', {
    cluster: '{{ env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER') }}',
    authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
        }
    }
});
```

You will need to add the CSRF-TOKEN otherwise you will get Page Expired errors.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try:
Try this:

Uncomment App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class in config/app.php
Use php artisan config:cache
Use php artisan route:cache
Check new route broadcasting/auth with php artisan route:list

[Source](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/243)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get closer to the answer. Its because Pusher by default tries `/pusher/auth` when Laravel by default uses `broadcasting/auth`